# Is there any verse or any quote we find in any of the scriptures talking abour racism?

Tags: vedas, puranas, bhagavad-gita

I am searching for any mentioning about racism in sacred scriptures like Puraans, Veds, Bhagawad Geeta or Upnishads?
I am unable to find it myself but I think there must be something. I will be happy if I find something here promptly.
Thank you!

Comment: Vedanta literature says all these feelings of race are due to Avidya(ignorance). What verses you exactly want? Supporting or condeming it?

Comment: For the racism part, [this QnA discussion](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/it-should-not-be-allowed-to-call-contemporary-eminent-western-sanskrit-scholars) , on the HSE META **might help you**, a bit.

Comment: Also, Welcome to HSE! Please visit the [FAQ INDEX](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/478/faq-index-for-hinduism-stack-exchange) , to get quickly started in here and have an enriching journey ahead!

Comment: Mr. Sethu Srivatsa Koduru, any verse would work. Maybe condemning?